# Does Monero/the CryptoNote Protocol support multi signature wallets?

Tags: cryptonote, ring-signatures, ringct, multisig

I did not find a question directly asking for multi signatures and Monero. Right now there doesn't seem to be support for multi signatures in Monero. So I want to know if it is technically feasible and if so what are the necessary development steps?

I found this question on multisig ([How does ringct interact with multisig?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-does-ringct-interact-with-multisig)) but it appears to be very specific in regards to RingCT.

Comment: See http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/782/can-you-have-a-multsig-wallet-with-the-current-monero-protocol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Monero does not support multisig at the moment. It will at some point, probably not very long after RingCT is merged, since that work relies on RingCT building blocks.

Cryptonote itself does not support multisig either, but Bytecoin (Cryptonote's first actual currency) does support it for mixin 0 (ie, without ring signatures involving other outputs). Monero's implementation will support ring signatures (which is the point of Cryptonote currencies).